# How to return an anonymous type after joining two models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application. and i have the following action method which return an ActionResult inside a Controller class :-

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term, string SearchBy)
{
    if (SearchBy == "Tag")
    {
        var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term.Trim()).ToList();
        var resources = repository.GetResources(tech.Select(a => a.IT360ID.Value).ToArray(), false).ToList();
        var query = from techItems in tech
                    join resourcesItems in resources
                    on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                    orderby techItems.PartialTag
                    select new { extra = true, label = techItems.Tag.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var activeResources = repository.FindActiveResourceByName(term.Trim(), true).ToList();//.OrderBy(p => p.RESOURCENAME).Select(a => new { label = a.RESOURCENAME }).ToList();
        var resources = repository.GetResources(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray(), false).ToList();
        var tech = repository.getTechnologiesByIT360ids(activeResources.Select(a=>a.RESOURCEID).ToArray()).ToList();
        var query = from techItems in tech
                    join resourcesItems in resources
                    on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                    orderby techItems.Tag
                    select new { extra = true, label = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = techItems.Tag.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


}
```

now i need this method to be used on another controller class. so i tried moving this method to a shared model class , and reference this shared model class from the two action methods. but i am not sure how i need to define the model class method definition. as i cannot/Shouldn't return an ActionResult from a model class so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: Why not create a method which returns a concrete type instead of an anonymous object?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov can you adivce more on this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably clean this is up some but to give you an idea of what you can do.  Create a new class and name it something that's meaningful.. I just used MyModel

```
public class MyModel
{
    public bool extra { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string techtype { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string resourcename { get; set; }
    public string sitename { get; set; }

    public static List<MyModel> AutoComplete(string term, string SearchBy)
    {
        using (var repository = new MyDataContext())
        {
            if (SearchBy == "Tag")
            {
                var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term.Trim()).ToList();
                var resources = repository.GetResources(tech.Select(a => a.IT360ID.Value).ToArray(), false).ToList();
                var query = from techItems in tech
                            join resourcesItems in resources
                            on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                            orderby techItems.PartialTag
                            select new MyModel { extra = true, label = techItems.Tag.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

                return query.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                var activeResources = repository.FindActiveResourceByName(term.Trim(), true).ToList();//.OrderBy(p => p.RESOURCENAME).Select(a => new { label = a.RESOURCENAME }).ToList();
                var resources = repository.GetResources(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray(), false).ToList();
                var tech = repository.getTechnologiesByIT360ids(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray()).ToList();
                var query = from techItems in tech
                            join resourcesItems in resources
                            on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                            orderby techItems.Tag
                            select new MyModel { extra = true, label = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = techItems.Tag.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now when you want to use this in your action result you can just call

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term, string SearchBy)
{
    return Json(MyModel.AutoComplete(term, SearchBy),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a class (view model) to be used by any code interested in building up a JSON result, like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteViewModel
{
    public bool extra { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string techtype { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public string resourcename { get; set; }
    public string sitename { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use the AutoCompleteViewModel as the return type for a separate method that builds/populates this object or in the LINQ query of your action method, like this:

```
public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term, string SearchBy)
{
    if (SearchBy == "Tag")
    {
        var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term.Trim()).ToList();
        var resources = repository.GetResources(tech.Select(a => a.IT360ID.Value).ToArray(), 
                                                false).ToList();
        var query = from techItems in tech
                    join resourcesItems in resources
                    on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID
                    orderby techItems.PartialTag
                    select new AutoCompleteViewModel { extra = true, 
                                                       label = techItems.Tag.ToString(), 
                                                techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, 
                                      status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, 
 customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

    return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else
{
    var activeResources = repository.FindActiveResourceByName(term.Trim(), true).ToList();//.OrderBy(p => p.RESOURCENAME).Select(a => new { label = a.RESOURCENAME }).ToList();
    var resources = repository.GetResources(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray(), false).ToList();
    var tech = repository.getTechnologiesByIT360ids(activeResources.Select(a=>a.RESOURCEID).ToArray()).ToList();
    var query = from techItems in tech
                join resourcesItems in resources
                on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                orderby techItems.Tag
                select new AutoCompleteViewModel { extra = true, label = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = techItems.Tag.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) as your shared model class return type.

Sample (untested!):

```
    public dynamic AutoCompleteService(string term, string SearchBy)
    {
        if (SearchBy == "Tag")
        {
            var tech = repository.AllFindTechnolog(term.Trim()).ToList();
            var resources = repository.GetResources(tech.Select(a => a.IT360ID.Value).ToArray(), false).ToList();
            var query = from techItems in tech
                        join resourcesItems in resources
                        on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                        orderby techItems.PartialTag
                        select new { extra = true, label = techItems.Tag.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            var activeResources = repository.FindActiveResourceByName(term.Trim(), true).ToList();//.OrderBy(p => p.RESOURCENAME).Select(a => new { label = a.RESOURCENAME }).ToList();
            var resources = repository.GetResources(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray(), false).ToList();
            var tech = repository.getTechnologiesByIT360ids(activeResources.Select(a => a.RESOURCEID).ToArray()).ToList();
            var query = from techItems in tech
                        join resourcesItems in resources
                        on techItems.IT360ID.Value equals resourcesItems.RESOURCEID // join based on db2ID
                        orderby techItems.Tag
                        select new { extra = true, label = resourcesItems.RESOURCENAME.ToString(), techtype = techItems.TechnologyType.Name, status = resourcesItems.ResourceState.DISPLAYSTATE, customername = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.ORG_NAME.ToString(), resourcename = techItems.Tag.ToString(), sitename = resourcesItems.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization.NAME };

            return query;
        }
    }
```

And change your Controller's method

```
    public ActionResult AutoComplete(string term, string SearchBy)
    {
        return Json(AutoCompleteService(term, SearchBy), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```